# IIS server consume 100% CPU

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am working on web site that is build on MVC version 2. We deployed this application on on Server 2008, site was working fine. Now we moved the site to 2012 server, same application consume 100% CPU sometime it release the server and use 1-10% of CPU. I am not able to trace the issue where is exact issue, please help me if anyone know how we can fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What helped me in the past is to use SysInternal's Process Explorer and inspect the stack trace of the IIS worker process. While this only gives a broad overview it still helped me to find some bottlenecks. Beside this you could install a performance profiler like ANTS on your server. I've also tried [LeanSentry](https://www.leansentry.com/) which I wasn't able to make it running on my servers, even with the help of their support.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
Is there any other way to trace the performance, because ANTS profiler is paid version?

Comment: You can try (for 10 days) DotTrace https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/?fromMenu maybe you will find the issue. Good luck.